# Emploi-t-on « taper » ou « appuyer » pour dire « tap » sur un téléphone ou une tablette ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, informatique, terminologie

J'ai pas mal recherché sur de divers forums pour la meilleure traduction de « tap » dans le sens:

> Tap on the [ ] icon on your iPhone/iPad/smartphone/tablet to open …

Je cherche l'avis des francophones natifs pour savoir si l'on dit plus souvent « taper » ou « appuyer » lorsqu'on se réfère à son appareil mobile.

Ou bien, est-ce qu'il existe d'autres mots pour dire la même chose ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sur les smartphones, on dit plutôt **presser**.

**Appuyer** se dit aussi.

**Toucher** se rencontre encore et serait peut-être le plus *juste* désormais:

[Comme le fait remarquer L'aditdabenlà](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18920/949) au milieu de sa réponse plus bas, il faut noter que *presser/appuyer* est un héritage des anciens PDA (assistants personnels, qui avaient ou non la fonction *téléphone*) et qui nécessitaient **réellement une pression**, certains avaient même un petit clavier. De nos jours, l'écran tactile est *capacitif* (c'est le fait de le *toucher une zone* qui est détecté, sans pression).

**Taper** (et également **cliquer**, **frapper**) est plutôt réservé aux claviers d'ordinateur, et par extension aux tablettes (grands claviers virtuels).

Mais comme les applications *web* ne sont pas nécessairement adaptées spécifiquement au terminal et cherchent à tout couvrir, on rencontre souvent ces derniers termes, mêmes pour des smartphones.

Answer (score 4):

Dans ce cas, « appuyer » est clairement une meilleure traduction de « tap » que « taper » ; taper a une connotation un peu violente, il faut donner des coups pour taper.

Quelques exemples:

> Appuyer sur l'icône « téléphone » pour faire un appel.

Et pour *long press* :

> Appuyer longuement sur l'entrée du carnet d'adresse pour l'éditer.

On pourrait considérer « cliquer » mais cela est plus adéquat lorsqu'on utilise une souris.

Comment: On tape sur un clavier....

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement je lis les manuels, et en général il s'agit assurément de [*toucher*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toucher/78627?q=toucher#77701) l'écran ou *de maintenir le doigt sur qqc.*, quand une fonction l'exige, et il va sans dire que la pression n'a rien à voir avec ce genre d'[écran tactile](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cran_tactile#Technologie_capacitive). *Toucher* est le terme qu'emploie *Apple* dans son manuel ([généralement](https://help.apple.com/iphone/9/?lang=fr#/iphc77652020), [application](https://help.apple.com/iphone/9/?lang=fr#/iph96b1e460)). [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=tap&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) note que celui du Samsung S4 disait *toucher* ; on dit maintenant [*appuyer*](http://www.devicemanuals.eu/fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/galaxy-S7-FR.pdf) semble-t-il. Dans les deux cas on retrouve une variante de *maintenir le doigt sur* pour l'idée de *hold* (*maintenir le doigt appuyé sur*, dit Samsung). Ne pas maintenir le doigt revient à uniquement faire une *touche*, ou simplement toucher. Concrètement on est peut-être plus habitué à *appuyer* sur des boutons, tandis qu'on *touche/tâte* une zone et peut-être que ça influence le choix selon le contexte. Quant à taper, il signifie comme on l'a dit ailleurs *écrire à la machine* et n'a rien à voir avec l'action sur un icône ; ce serait un simple calque sémantique de *tap*. Mais on peut choisir l'action concrète ou le paradigme de l'interface et ses métaphores, ce qu'on trouve de plus usuel avec les objets, et même taper sur l'icône à coups de poing quoique avec résultats mitigés. Reste que tous les verbes sont utiles.

Comment: Le mot "Toucher" dans ces manuels n'a pas été choisi par des francophones natifs.

Comment: @user2987828 Vous les connaissez ? Qu'est-ce qui vous fait dire ça ? Je suis francophone et _toucher_ est un excellent choix à mon avis. Merci.

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce contexte, on dit plutôt **sélectionner**.

Answer (score 1):

Voici encore une autre façon de rendre ce verbe en français. L'équivalent est certes informel mais assez neutre : en utilisant le verbe *FAIRE*.

Exemples :

> 1. ***Fais*** cmd+P/Enter pour imprimer ton texte.
> 2. Tu gagnerais un temps fou ***en faisant*** simplement ctrl+C/ctrl+V (au lieu de te tuer à faire tous ces copier-coller à la souris).
> 3. Bien que les taquets n'aient pas de secrets pour moi, il m'arrive encore, par fainéantise, de ***faire*** « tab, tab, tab... » pour inscrire mon nom à droite de la page.

Comment: Cette option fonctionne lorsqu'on parle d'un clavier, mais pas dans le contexte d'un téléphone ou d'une tablette. On ne peut pas "faire l'icône X" ou "faire l'app Y".

Answer (score 0):

Mais du coup, pour des textes plus commerciaux du style "en quelques clics, vous aurez ce résultat", ça se traduit comment pour le mobile? "En quelques pressions"? "En quelques tapes"?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20845)